# Is there any guideline to determine one question is Off-Topic or not?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Say, this question I just answered [Linux: how to check if a drive is mount to nfs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17713563/29489) has been flagged by many as off-topic but this one [Force unmount of NFS-mounted directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317/force-unmount-of-nfs-mounted-directory) is not, but IMHO above two are exactly same kind of question.

So is there any guideline to decide what's off-topic?

Comment: The  second question is five years old and was posted at a time when the rules were very different. It is no longer a good fit for the site.

Comment: You can find the guideline here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @George, Thanks that make sense.

Comment: I'll add that I think all the given links here are obsolete/incomplete. The common "I need to do X. Is there any library to do it?" is ok by any reading on what can you ask here (a specific programming problem, software tools commonly used by programmers) and isn't against and "don't ask this here" because which libraries are present is a fact, not an opinion (I'm not asking which one is the best), still it's considered a "don't ask this here" because "the response could become obsolete in a month or two"

Comment: they should both be locked(or protected) not only closed.

Answer (score 0):

The help section has a canonical section about [asking on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Another thing you can get hints regarding what to avoid in the close dialog:

1. **duplicate of...**
   This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
2. **off-topic because...**
   This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.
3. **unclear what you're asking**
   Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
4. **too broad**
   There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
5. **primarily opinion-based**
   Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.